# Including Windows API calls in my Ogre Application

Tags: windows, winapi, multi-touch, gestures, ogre

i'm developing an Ogre application and i'm adding support to touch and gestures to it, because i want to use it on touch-enabled PCs.

Very well, after searching the web, i've found the Windows Gestures API http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . It suports not only touch recognition but gesture interpretation, which sounds just great!

I want to include it in my application, but my question is: this Windows sample creates its own window, its own main loops, how do i include it in my ogre app using my ogre window?

Comment: Does OGRE allow you access to its underlying windows message pump?

Comment: Yes, i believe so. Even more, OGRE sample application includes windows.h and its main function is `INT WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR strCmdLine, INT )`. Perhaps i just have to find a way to link this with `WndProc`.

Comment: If you can access the message pump then you should be able to use that to insert your own WM_GESTURE handler.

Comment: Can you send me a reference or tell me how can i insert and watch an event handler? thank you very much!

Comment: You're going to have to ask someone who knows Ogre unfortunately.  If you can somehow get hooked into the wndproc, it should be easy.

Comment: As i can see, i have to make the same calls that i would make if it was a simple win32 code. Now i´m able to call WndProcedure, i just have now to retrieve the values of the API. Almost there.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Ogre::Root::startRendering you would call Ogre::Root::renderOneFrame in your main application loop.

If you want to use OIS for mouse/keyboard input take a look at this: [Using OIS](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Using%20OIS)

But remember: Ogre is cross platform, but you program won't be if you use a windows native API.